# Codeigniter 2.1, Jquery - 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am experiencing 500 Internal Server Error when I try to reach **global_info** controller via JQ $.post function, and this is happening only with this function.

CI controller code:

```
function gi_get_ad_payment_code()
        {
            $q = $this->db->get_where('code_payment', array('code' => $_POST['code']));
            if ($q->num_rows() == 0 ){
                show_error('Whoops, no results :(');
            } else
            {
                 $q = $q->row();
                 echo $time = substr($q->code, 12, 2);
            }
```

JQ code:

```
var forma = $('form#mali_oglas'),
pomoc = $('div[role=pomoc]'),
div = $('.mali_oglas_pomoc'),
input = forma.find('input, textarea'),
code = forma.find('#code'),
cct = $.cookie('csrf_token_name');

code.on('focusout', function(){
    var url = '<?php echo base_url() ?>global_info/gi_get_ad_payment_code',
    data = $(this).val();
    $.post(url, {code : data, 'csrf_token_name': cct}, function(){
        console.log(code);
        $('.mali_oglas_img_paid').slideDown('slow');
        code.after('<input type="hidden" name="time" value="'+ data +'" />');
        code.after('<input type="hidden" name="paid" value="1" />');
    });
});
```

When I try some other controllers, this is working fine (I also use $.post in other places with controllers that are not **global_info** and everything is working fine). What seems to be the problem here?

Comment: whats the error (and stack trace if available) when you access the page via POST?

Comment: 500 Internal Server Error is the only error I get.

Comment: can you place de `global_info` controller declaration?

Comment: I deleted the old controller, and created the new one and everything is working well.

Answer (score 0):

I once had this also with CI and basically it had something to do with the encoding of the controller file (UTF-8, ANSI, ...). I also recreated the controller which solved my problems.

By the way, a neater way of making your URL in your view is `<?php echo base_url('global_info/gi_get_ad_payment_code'); ?>`